# Docker "is not a valid port number or address:port pair."

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, port

I am new in docker. I want to run my django app on port 9000. After command docker-compose up I am getting this message

```
Creating motion_full_version_backend_1 ... done
Attaching to motion_full_version_backend_1
backend_1  | Unknown command: 'makemigrations\r'. Did you mean makemigrations?
backend_1  | Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
backend_1  | Unknown command: 'migrate\r'. Did you mean migrate?
backend_1  | Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.*
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -qqy \
        wget \
        bzip2 \
        graphviz

RUN mkdir -p /backend

COPY ./backend/requirements.yml /backend/requirements.yml

# Create environment
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda env create -f /backend/requirements.yml

# Add env path to environment
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/backend/bin:$PATH
# Activate interpreter
RUN echo "source activate backend" >~/.bashrc

# Create a scripts folder
RUN mkdir -p /scripts
COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN chmod +x ./scripts*


COPY ./backend /backend

WORKDIR /backend
```

I am using script to run it

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
```

my docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./envs/dev.env
    command: 'sh /scripts/dev.sh'
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your script has windows linefeeds within it, e.g. the `\r` you see in the output:

```
makemigrations\r
```

Since docker is running this command within a Linux environment, you need to adjust your script linefeeds for the Linux `\n` (without any `\r`). Linux sees those carriage returns as part of the string in the command you are running or port number you are passing. Adjust the linefeeds in your editor or using a tool like dos2unix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but what do you mean to write script linefeed? When I write it like this is doesn´t work python manage.py makemigrations & python manage.py migrate & python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000

Comment: @Michaela I might be able to better answer with details on what editor you are using to edit the script.

Comment: I am using PyCharm

Comment: @Michaela I'm seeing the following documentation for configuring linefeeds in pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html